# How to determine the number of weak classifiers in ada boost

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, classification

I want to ask a question:
How many weak classifiers do you normaly use in an ada boost classification algorithm. For example if I have a number of features like 8000 features obtained with a feature detector like haris, hog, sift or whatever, how do I usually determine the number of weak classifiers for this nr of features. I have thought of using 1 weak classifier for each type of feature and make the weighted sum in this manner. I am afraid that it may overfit...

Comment: I have found this link http://www.quora.com/Machine-Learning/In-using-Adaboost-in-Classification-typically-how-many-weak-classifiers-is-expected-to-have-Also-does-an-unbalanced-training-set-more-than-+-greatly-affect-the-classifier however I don't think that 10 weak classifiers would suffice for 8000 features...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To suffice what I found, the maximum number of weak learnenrs can be equal to the maximum number of features and the minimum number can be determined experimentally or you could try AdrienNK suggestion

Answer (score 1):

To get the parameters of your model you should do cross-validation.

If the size of your database allows it (you have sufficient samples) you could split your learning set to get a validation set. Cross validation works that way : you learn only to ~75% of your learning set and then test the score onto the remaining ~25%. And then you do that for different values of your parameters and pick the value that lead to the higest score.

If the size of you database doesn't allow it you can do k-fold cross-validation (I won't explain it here but you can look it up on wikipedia).

Scikit-learn implements a tool called gridsearch that will "automatically" do that if you provide it with the right things.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html